# Visual studio code error when terminal killed using trash bin icon

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, terminal, npm-start

Mac user / Visual Studio Code

Two problems.

1. To finish npm start, press control+z or command+c, not working at all.
2. Then I click the trash bin icon to kill them, and the error is below.

The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'clean-exit', code: '1')

Every time I want to finish npm start, I quit Visual Studio Code and open it again.